# Incorrect database set up, null value on IList

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I've saved data from an api call into my database, but when trying to print the data to the page i'm getting a Object reference not set to an instance of an object error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I'm trying to access the image_url property on my card details view, but it keeps breaking

My Models:

```
public class Card
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? Atk { get; set; }
        public int? Def { get; set; }
        public string Desc {get; set;}
        public int? Level { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Attribute { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Image")]
        public IList<Image> Card_Images { get; set; }

        public IList<Deck> Deck { get; set; }
    }

 public class Image
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string image_url { get; set; }
        public string image_url_small{ get; set;  }
    }
```

My controller action :

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var card = _context.Cards.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            if (card == null)
                return HttpNotFound();

            return View(card);
        }
```

My database tables etc (as presented in VS server explorer):

```
Cards
    Id (key sign here)
    Name
    Atk
    Def
    Desc
    Level
    Type
    Attribute

Images
    Id (key sign here)
    image_url
    image_urul_small
    Card_Id
```

My view:

```
@model YGOBuilder.Models.Card

<div>
    <h4>Card</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Atk)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Atk)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Def)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Def)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Desc)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Desc)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Level)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Level)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Type)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Type)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Attribute)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Attribute)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Card_Images)
        </dt>

        @foreach (var item in Model.Card_Images)
        {
            foreach (var i in item.image_url)
            {
                <td>
                    <img src=@i height="300" width="200">
                </td>
            }

        }



    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

I am trying to pull through the image_url property connected to my model to be displayed on the view but it seems to trip up on here:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Card_Images)
```

Comment: Should Model in `Model.Card_Images` be lowercase?

Comment: Nothing is setting `Card_Images` to anything. Is this Code First, or Database First?

Comment: @GabrielLuci this is code first :)

Comment: @InfiniteHigh lowercase doesnt work

Comment: The two classes are joined by the Id so you have to make sure the model is showing the Id is used to link the two tables.

Comment: @jdweng can you more specific and give a code example? i.e which model should have the id on? maybe a code snippet if you are feeling generous?

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/new-database#2-create-the-model), relationships should be declared as `virtual List<>`. I suspect `IList` would still work, but `virtual` is more important.

But also, it needs to know how to join the tables, so you need ID properties that match in name.

```
public class Card
{
    public int CardId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Atk { get; set; }
    public int? Def { get; set; }
    public string Desc {get; set;}
    public int? Level { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Attribute { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Image")]
    public virtual List<Image> Images { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Deck> Decks { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public int CardId { get; set; }
    public string image_url { get; set; }
    public string image_url_small{ get; set;  }
}
```

Notice `ImageId`, `CardId`, and the added `CardId` property in the `Image` class. This is how it knows which `Image` belongs to which `Card`.

You will likely have to do the same in your `Deck` class.

You are also looping over `item.image_url`, which is a `string`. The effect is that you loop over every character in the string. You don't need that inner loop. Just use `item.image_url` in the `img` tag:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Card_Images)
{
    <td>
        <img src="@item.image_url" height="300" width="200">
    </td>
}
```

Comment: this kind of work, except now its print loads of blank imges to the page, when i open image in new tab it gives the error The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in 'YGOBuilder.Controllers.CardController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: I updated my answer. This is what jdweng was talking about.

Comment: so i've managed to print out a working image, however its printing about 30 of them, looking at the source its printing out an image for each char in the link

Comment: @GabrielLuci declaring the relationships as virtual just enables lazy loading. Also, the CardId is not required to define the relationship, granted it makes it easier, but if no foreign key is defined it will treat the entity as a Shadow Property. Which basically means that entity framework will make a foreign key property in the database for this, but you will not have direct access to that foreign key from the model.

Comment: @AndyStav if you had already done a database migration, I am not sure the CardId is doing what you think it is doing. The virtual modifier is probably what fixed your problem. There is one thing you should be aware of though. By enabling lazy loading, if you decide to serialize your data in the future, you might just serialize your entire database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the collection properties in the query. It will not lazy load them. Try using the following in your details method.

```
var card = _context.Cards.Include(c => c.Card_Images).Include(c => c.Deck).SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
```

Here is the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data . The virtual modifier turns on lazy loading. So, you would only use it if you want that property to be lazy loaded every time. Which in some cases, could cause entirely too much information to be requested.

Comment: I'm getting the error for c => c.Card_Images Cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it is not a delegate type

Comment: That is in your view. Replace "        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Card_Images)
        </dt>" in your view page

Comment: Also, you are adding td elements instead of dd elements in your foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Card_Images)
        {

                <td>
                    <img src=@item.image_url height="300" width="200">
                </td>

        }
```

and

```
public virtual List<Image> Images { get; set; }

public virtual List<Deck> Decks { get; set; }
```

fixed it, thanks to all for your input!